# How to select a group lines by your content of a file in GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, command

Good days. I have a problem. I have that get the lines that has a content specified. The command `grep` allow search a content specified of a file, but this line by line. I would like to select a content of various lines.
How to do this?
something as

```
cat -n /etc/profile | grep "
   if [ "$DISPLAY" != "" ]
   then
       xhost +si:localuser:root
   fi
"
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting to research `grep` with option `-z`.

---

But better option is `awk`.

With `awk` it is possible to select a range `awk '/RegExp1/,/RegExp2/' input.txt`

In your case:

```
 awk '/if/,/fi/{print}' input.txt
```

Will print all lines in `if` `fi` range.

---

Also With `awk` it is possible to define record separator with `RS` variable. For example record separator is empty line. `awk '1' RS="\n\n"`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much by the answer, it works! But and if I want an if with a conditional specific? As  `if [ "$DISPLAY" != "" ]`. How to do I this? Doing `awk "/if\b[\b\"$DISPLAY\"\b!=\b\"\"\b]/,/fi/{print}" /etc/profile` don't work neither `awk "/if [ "$DISPLAY" != "" ]/,/fi/{print}" /etc/profile` either.

Comment: Notice `awk` script is using single quote `'`. Also use the `gawk` RegExp pattern rules as specified here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators. In `awk` you will have to escape `$` as well `\$` in order to prevent `awk` field expansion.

Answer (score 0):

at end, I solve it, so...

```
sed -i "$(cat -n /etc/profile | gawk '/if \[ "\$DISPLAY" != "" \]/,/fi/{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//g' | sed -E 's/,(.+),/,/g')d" /etc/profile
```

1. `cat -n /etc/profile` shows the file content and line numbers

   ```
      27    if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
      28      for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
      29        if [ -r $i ]; then
      30          . $i
      31        fi
      32      done
      33      unset i
      34    fi
      35    #start
      36    if [ "$DISPLAY" != "" ]
      37    then
      38        xhost +si:localuser:root
      39    fi
      40    #end
   ```
2. Thank you to @Dudi Boy this command `gawk '/if \[ "\$DISPLAY" != "" \]/,/fi/{print $1}'` show the lines of section specified.

   ```
      36
      37
      38
      39
   ```
3. Now I replace the `\n` by `,`: `tr '\n' ','`

   ```
      36,37,38,39,
   ```
4. I delete the last comma (,): `sed 's/,$//g'`

   ```
      36,37,38,39
   ```
5. And get only the first and last numbers separed by comma (,): `sed -E 's/,(.+),/,/g'`

   ```
      36,39
   ```
6. Finally the result I execute it in a command `sed`: `sed -i "$(cat -n /etc/profile | gawk '/if \[ "\$DISPLAY" != "" \]/,/fi/{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//g' | sed -E 's/,(.+),/,/g')d" /etc/profile`

The result is

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r $i ]; then
            . $i
        fi
    done
    unset i
fi
#start
#end
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to accomplish the task of removing/substruct the ranged section with one`qawk` command:

```
 gawk -i inplace '/if \[ "\$DISPLAY" != "" \]/,/fi/{next}1' /etc/profile
```